# understanding cyclic/recursive data types in haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, types

I'm trying to *fully* understand haskell's data types, so I created these:

```
data District = District {nameOfCity :: String, 
                          subDistricts ::[DistrictUnit]} 
                          deriving (Show, Eq)

data DistrictUnit = DistrictUnit District 
                    | BranchUnit Branch
                    deriving (Show, Eq)

data Branch = Branch {nameOfBranch :: String,
                      numOfEmployees :: Int,
                      sales :: Int}
                      deriving (Show, Eq)
```

Here are some examples:

```
a = District {nameOfCity = "Berlin", subDistrcits = []}

b = District {nameOfCity = "New York", 
             subDistricts = 
             [DistrictUnit
             (District {nameOfCity = "Amsterdam",
             subDistricts = 
             [DistrictUnit
             (District {nameOfCity = "London",
             subDistricts = []})]})]}

c = District {nameOfCity = "Iowa" , 
             subDistricts = 
             [BranchUnit
             (Branch {nameOfBranch = "Omaha",            
             numOfEmployees = 3, 
             sales = 2343})]}
```

Now I'm trying to build two functions: getNameOfCity and getNameOfBranch:

```
getNameOfCity b -> ["New York", "Amsterdam", "London"]
```

But I have massive pattern matching issues. I just don't know how to build a function that works for **all** inputs.

Here are my attempts:

```
getNameOfCity :: District -> [String]
getNameOfCity (District a b) = [a]
```

This function will only give me the first name:

```
["New York"]
```

So I tried this:

```
getNameOfCity (District a [DistrictUnit (District b c)]) = [a, b]
```

And (of course) that one will only give me the first two names:

```
["New York", "Amsterdam"]
```

How can I make that getNameOfCity work for all inputs? And will getNamesOfBranch work the same way (since it has different parameters)? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: `District` and `DistrictUnit` look like a parent-child relationship which should be cyclic, but you did not make it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to do everything with a single function, it's easier to write separate helpers:

```
allDistrictNames :: District -> [String]  -- This was your `getNameOfCity`
allDistrictNames_u :: DistrictUnit -> [String]
allDistrictNames_ul :: [DistrictUnit] -> [String]
```

`allDistrictNames` and `allDistrictNames_u` can now be implemented with simple pattern matches and calls to each other. `allDistrictNames_ul` needs to call `allDistrictNames_u` on all list elements, and combine the results. There's [a standard function for this exact purpose](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concatMap).

Comment: I still have the same problem, I don't know which pattern to use. I tried allDistrictNames_u :: DistrictUnit -> [String] ; allDistrictNames_u (DistrictUnit (District a _)) = [a] and I still don't get all names

Comment: @nanemuna You have to make these functions mutually recursive. Don't match against `(DistrictUnit (District a _))`, match against `(DistrictUnit (District a dus))` where we have `dus :: [DistrictUnit]`. Hence, we can call `allDistrictNames_ul dus` and combine that with `a`.

Answer (score 0):

You want `getNameOfCity` applied to a `District` to return its `nameOfCity` field, prepended to the list of city names from each of its `subDistricts` that are `District`s and not `Branch`es.

So you had a good starting point with something like this:

```
getNameOfCity :: District -> [String]
getNameOfCity (District name units) = [name]
```

But of course you need to do something with `units`. The pattern you wrote in your second example, `[DistrictUnit (District b c)]`, only matches when the `subDistricts` field contains a list of exactly one element, where that element is also a `DistrictUnit`, and extracts only the `nameOfCity` field (`b`) from that district, ignoring any further nested subdistricts (in `c`).

To help you with this, I’m going to give you a template for you to fill in, following a common pattern that’s very helpful when you’re getting familiar with Haskell: working back from the desired result, breaking down the problem into small steps, and giving each step a name and a type signature. That way, if you make a mistake, the compiler will produce much more comprehensible error messages. Then, once you have a working solution, you can remove the intermediate variables and consolidate the steps into a more compact expression.

First, your desired result is the root district name prepended to the list of names of all subdistricts.

```
getNameOfCity :: District -> [String]
getNameOfCity (District name units) = let

  allCities :: [String]
  allCities = …

  in name : allCities
```

To construct this, you’ll need to iterate over the `units` and extract the names from each district, then concatenate all the results.

```
getNameOfCity :: District -> [String]
getNameOfCity (District name units) = let

  districtCities :: [[String]]
  districtCities = …  -- List of list of city names for each ‘District’

  allCities :: [String]
  allCities = …  -- Concatenated ‘districtCities’

  in name : allCities
```

The iteration over the units can be done in a few ways, but what I would do is extract only the `District`s first so you have a narrower, more precise type to work with, and then you can simply apply `getNameOfCity` recursively on them.

```
getNameOfCity :: District -> [String]
getNameOfCity (District name units) = let

  -- Extract only those ‘units’ that are ‘District’s
  districts :: [District]
  districts = …
    -- Hint:
    --   Hoogle ‘(a -> Maybe b) -> [a] -> [b]’
    --   and define ‘getDistrict :: DistrictUnit -> Maybe District’;
    --   or use a list comprehension of the form: ‘[… | … <- units]’

  districtCities :: [[String]]
  districtCities = …

  allCities :: [String]
  allCities = …

  in name : allCities
```

You could follow a very similar approach for the branch names; it’s a good exercise to consider how you might abstract over the commonalities, once you have both of them in front of you.

---

It’s also a common higher-level approach to solve this sort of problem using the `Semigroup` & `Monoid` typeclasses, which are mathy names for the sets of types that can be “appended” associatively in some way (the `<>` operator), and have a default “empty” value (`mempty`) which is a no-op for appending. The general method is to `map` each value to a “summary” value—here, the list of city names—and then `fold` those summaries together, conveniently combined into a single operation called `foldMap`. For instance:

```
districtCities :: District -> [String]
districtCities (District city units) = [city] <> foldMap unitCities units

unitCities :: DistrictUnit -> [String]

-- Recursively summarise district.
unitCities (DistrictUnit district) = districtCities district

-- Return “empty” value for branch.
unitCities (BranchUnit branch) = mempty
```

This generalises to accumulating other fields, like the branch names:

```
districtBranches :: District -> [String]
districtBranches (District _ units) = foldMap unitBranches units

unitBranches :: DistrictUnit -> [String]
unitBranches (DistrictUnit district) = districtBranches district
unitBranches (BranchUnit branch) = [nameOfBranch branch]
```

Or other types of values, like the total sales, using the `Sum` monoid:

```
import Data.Monoid (Sum(..))

totalSales :: District -> Int
totalSales district = getSum (districtSales district)
-- Or: totalSales = getSum . districtSales

districtSales :: District -> Sum Int
districtSales (District _ units) = foldMap unitSales units

unitSales :: DistrictUnit -> Sum Int
unitSales (DistrictUnit district) = foldMap districtSales district
unitSales (BranchUnit branch) = Sum (branchSales branch)
```

Or even multiple values at once, using e.g.: `(Sum 1, ["London"]) <> (Sum 2, ["Paris"])` = `(Sum 3, ["London", "Paris"])`. Notice how all these implementations have similar structure, too, though, and consider how you might abstract over this “folding” pattern generically.